# Spring Security authenticationFailure : error org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring security to do authentication,so what i done is to  implements a `UserDetailsService`, and i used a UserDao to get user from database.so i have two file configurations applicationContext and security : the problem is  when i debug , i get:

`error org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread` at `DaoAuthenticationProvider` class and the weird thing is in  `UserDetailsService` the session is instantiated .

ApplicationContext:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/InTouch" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource">
                <ref bean="dataSource" />
            </property>
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
    ......
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">/tmp/lucene_dev</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory">
                <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
            </property>
        </bean>

> <aop:config>      <aop:pointcut id="transactionPointcut"
>           expression="execution(*
> ma.csimaroc.core.profil.services.interfaces..*.*(..))" />
>       <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice"
> pointcut-ref="transactionPointcut" />     </aop:config>
```

security.xml :

```
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"
    id="passwordEncoder" />

    <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"
        class="ma.csimaroc.core.profil.services.impl.CustomUserDetailsService"
        autowire="byName" />

    <beans:bean id="authProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="authProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
```

CustomUserDetailsService  :

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

UserDao userDao;

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    UserDetails user = null;

    UserBD userBean = userDao.getUserByName(username);

    System.out.println(userBean.getUsername());

    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userBean.getUserRole()
            .getRole()));

    user = new User(userBean.getUsername(), userBean.getPassword()
            .toLowerCase(), true, true, true, true, authList);

    return user;
}

public UserDao getUserDao() {
    return userDao;
}

public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
}
```

web.xml :

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
                     /WEB-INF/security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare into ApplicationContext:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

In order to use tx declare the following xml namespace:

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
```

This will enable `@Transactional` annotation.

Then annotate with  `@Transactional` your `CustomUserDetailsService`

hope this helps.

Comment: i am using <aop:config>
  <aop:pointcut id="transactionPointcut"
   expression="execution(* ma.csimaroc.core.profil.services.interfaces..*.*(..))" />
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="transactionPointcut" />
 </aop:config>